# Mysql server request a lot for no reason

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, request, apache2, debian

I have i just a problem yesterday on my server, i don't know why but every 2 seconds 9 questions "request" is executed, but the problem is the server is just configured, no website on it.

Watch the screen

http://hpics.li/6b1d071
http://hpics.li/8d116a2

Comment: Use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to see the queries that are coming in. This may give a clue to where they're coming from.

Comment: only one thing is output see it, http://hpics.li/27867bc , do you think phpMyAdmin can cause it?

Comment: If you can't see the queries this way, perhaps because they complete too quickly to catch them, try turning on the query log.